# How to pass a value from a function to a variable in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, function

anyone. The problem is passing the return value of a function in Angular to a variable.
Where am I going wrong? Is it an observable that returns?

file **SERVICE**

```
number_record(year: number): any {
    // return the value
    return this.http.get(`${this.url + 'doc_number'}/${year}`).pipe(
      map((res) => {
        const resInt = +res;
        console.log('Number record: ' + resInt);
        return resInt;
      })
    );
  }
```

The document number is being returned from the database. I put the logs to show the result.

file **TS** component

```
find_number_doc(year: number): number {
    return this.service.number_record(year).subscribe((rest: number) => {
      //this.number_doc = rest;
      console.log('Number find: ' + rest);
    });
  }


 ngOnInit() {

 *this.number_doc = this.find_number_doc(this.year);

 }
```

*Here I cannot assign the value of the returned document.

Answer (score 2):

correct your code

```
find_number_doc(year: number): number {
    return this.service.number_record(year).subscribe((rest: number) => {
      **this.number_doc = rest;**
      console.log('Number find: ' + rest);
    });
  }


 ngOnInit() {
     **this.find_number_doc(this.year);**
     }
```